# How to get text data from webpage

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get data form a website about institution using XMLHttpRequest but rather than data I am getting error page please help

My code:-

```
var url = '[https://tsecet.nic.in/institute_details.aspx?iCode=JNTH][3]';
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       document.write( this.responseText);
    }
}

xhttp.open("GET", url , true);
xhttp.send();
```

Target Web Page Address:-
https://tsecet.nic.in/institute_details.aspx?iCode=JNTH

**If I try to open**
https://tsecet.nic.in/Default.aspx>>then click on >>
[institute profile](https://tsecet.nic.in/institute_profile.aspx) >> then click on>>[JNTH](https://tsecet.nic.in/institute_details.aspx?iCode=JNTH) 
**Then I am able to get data in *browser* Else I am redirected to an error page**

***Please help me...***

**Note**

> I am trying to get this data from a different website and a different
>   domain This website is scripted in aspx

Comment: Are you running this javascript inside the same domain or on a different website?

Comment: @PSK __different domain different website

Comment: https://tsecet.nic.in/institute_details.aspx?iCode=JNTH is a 302 redirect to https://tsecet.nic.in/ErrorPage.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/institute_details.aspx

Comment: @sideshowbarker how to fix it

Comment: If I try to open   https://tsecet.nic.in/Default.aspx >> https://tsecet.nic.in/institute_profile.aspx >> https://tsecet.nic.in/institute_details.aspx?iCode=JNTH  Then I am able to get data in browser else I am redirected to an error page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX request you're trying to run can't do that, as the pages have the `X-XSS-Protection: 1` header, [blocking such requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection). It looks as if they allow the internals URIs to launch only within a "frame" set by the homepage. Unfortunately, I can't tell for sure. In short, you are going to need another approach.

Comment: So how can I? Any other approach??

Comment: I have added the ASP.net tag to your question, so ASP developers can check it out. Are you trying to collect the rows in the final URL?